# Write a Java program that reads a large file of strings and determines whether all the strings are unique

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I need to finish the part of the program that finds if there are any duplicates in the read in text files. The given base code is as follows,

```
public class Lab6
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
    {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader infile =  new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ) );
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (infile.ready())
                    list.add( infile.readLine() );
            infile.close();
            System.out.printf( "List contains %d Strings.\n",list.size());
            boolean hasDupe = false;
            String dupe="";

            /*  YOUR CODE IN HERE
                    SET hasDupe to T/F
                    Do it EFFICIENTLY! i.e. < N squared
            */

            if (hasDupe)
                    System.out.println("List contains dupe: " + dupe );
            else
                    System.out.println("List contains NO dupes.");
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long ms = endTime-startTime;
            System.out.printf("Elapsed time: %f seconds\n", ms/1000.0);
    }
}
```

I need to finish it without using a brute force method.

Comment: Do you really need to use that code base in particular? There is a MUCH more efficient solution than that.

Comment: What stops you? What is your question?

Comment: Don't have us solve your homework! Try it yourself and ask question about specific issues you run into.

Comment: I need to use this particular base code. And the thing that is stopping me is that I have no idea what to put for the your code in here part. My professor said to use the collection library to sort it and find the duplicates

Answer (score 2):

You can just create an HashSet object and start adding all your strings to it. If there is a duplicate, HashSet will return a false on the add() method and that is your cue for a duplicate. You can finish it in O(n) time.

Comment: We haven't learned HashSet yet so I can;t use it.

Comment: @user3357011 that is _always_ the problem with so-called professors... They won't allow their pupils to be ahead of time.

Comment: @user3357011 "My professor said to use the collection library" `HashSet` belongs to collections library.

Comment: Then one option would be to sort the set of strings (O(n log n)) and then iterate over them and at each step, consider the current string and the next and find out if they are equal. You should be able to do it in O(n log n) time.

Comment: Are you able to sort the list then? If yes, why not just sort it and simply use a single for loop check if there is two consecutive elements are the same?